# Expressão regular PHP - Texto de um site

Tags: php, string

Tenho uma string

Valor da Causa: `<'span id="i_valorCausa'">51.899,51<'/span'><'BR'>`

Preciso pegar o que esta entre `<'span id="i_valorCausa'>  <'/span'>`

Tentei assim:

O `$content` é de onde vem a string.

```
preg_match_all("/<span id='i_valorCausa'>(.*)<\span>/", $content, $prices); 

echo $prices[1];
```

mas não funcionou. alguém pode me ajudar?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Esse html está um pouco estranho. Tem aspas/pelicas a mais, é mesmo isso?

Answer (score 0):

você deve colocar como uma matriz assim: (`$prices[1][0];`)

```
$content = "<span id='i_valorCausa'>hduehuedheudheu<span>";

preg_match_all("/<span id='i_valorCausa'>(.*)<span>/", $content, $prices); 

echo $prices[1][0];
```

fiz o teste nesse [site](http://www.writephponline.com/)

Como diz na documentação do [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php)

**Parâmetros** 
pattern
O padrão a procurar, como uma string.

**subject**
A string de entrada.

**matches**
Array de todas as combinações em matriz multidimensional ordenada de acordo com flags.

como você não colocou flag, ele vai retornar em um array `multidimensional`